# Android GCC compiler change

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

How to change the default GCC compiler from 4.6 to 4.8 in ndk-build command? I want to use the arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 but by default its arm-linux-androideabi-4.6. Is there any way to do so ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly call `ndk-build NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8`, or set this inside jni/**Application.mk**:

`NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION:=4.8`